# Extract matches from a search

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way that after performing a search for a specific phrase, I could extract the list of the matches?

So far I had two use cases for that:

1. I wanted to see all unique values in a huge CSS file for a specific attribute. For example searching for `font\-size\:[0-9]{2}px;`
2. A PHP project I got has a class that performs Translation. It uses an array. I wanted to extract a list of array elements that are being used like `Translation\:\:translate\(\"[a-zA-Z\_]+\"\)`

The searches work great but I would like to use the output of them in some way

Comment: You could use some of the tools your OS provides e.g. [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) on Linux or the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3) command on Windows when using Powershell.

Comment: only the escape of `(` and `)` are needed, you can remove all other backslashes

Comment: What do you mean by " I would like to use the output of them in some way"?  If you just want to view them then open in the results in a search editor with an adjustable number of context lines around the result.  It is a condensed view  into your results.

Comment: I would like the list of matches, I can view them any time, but I would like to export them to a CSV